# Text position got changed after JSON is loaded on canvas in fabricJS

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, position, fabricjs

I have observed change in position of text when creating fresh on canvas and when JSON is loaded on canvas. Normally on moving element on canvas values for left and top goes upto 14 decimal places and when JSON is loaded the position comes out to be upto two places.

e.g. In picture1 text left position  is 294.63668348469565 and text top is 202.79140935082407 after saving and loading back JSON, positon slightly got changed but left is 294.63 and top is 202.80 (picture2)
[picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bblqA.png)
[picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFe9w.png)

I guess upto 14 decimal is for very precision, does less decimal places can govern this change?

Comment: Unless there are some super high scale factors in the game, to me  it looks like there is some other problem.
The difference is too big to be a third decimal rounding.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi, I believe you are right becuase on loading from JSON I added 14 decaimal value and rendered it again, it showed no effect. what It can be any clue? Thanks

Comment: To me it looks like you are not reloading the font in the correct way, you get a probably bigger or smaller width/height and this set calculation off. are you using originX = originY = center

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi, thanks for the catch yes it was width and height issue.The JSON I receive has value say 225.96 but after canvas.loadFromJSON the width comes out to be less say for e.g. 204.31 (example for reference),so  it was reassigned and rendered, now working. Thanks for the catch

Comment: But curved Text seems to have an issue, I have tested cases out of 10 cases, 4  seems to be on same position but in 6 cases they are slightly deflected from their original position, even fixed width and height and also radius (different values) but still no luck. @AndreaBogazzi

Comment: well i have no idea how curvedText behaves. it may be a font loading problem, please be sure to load the font fully before starting fabric logic.

Answer (score 2):

By defualt precision value is 2.

If you want to change you can use [NUM_FRACTION_DIGITS](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#.NUM_FRACTION_DIGITS)

```
fabric.Object.NUM_FRACTION_DIGITS = value;
```

Where value is in your case 14.

Comment: Thnx for the answer, I tried to enter 14 digit decimal value and then rendered it again, no effect. Initially I thought it might be because of coordinates but it seems not to be. Any other clue what it can be? or I should look.

Answer (score 0):

So got it fixed, not the best solution but working fine.

First of all thanx to @AndreaBogazzi for the catch on width and height for the text, so re-assigned the values after items get loaded on canvas and rendered it.

But for `curvedText` element obeserved the same problem so I did some work around to fix it, first I get all the properties of existing curvedText element `props = obj.toObject()` then `var textSample = new fabric.CurvedText(obj.getText(), props)` and then  :

`canvas.getObjects().splice(key,1) //@ remove the old curved text element`

`canvas.add(textSample) //@ add the curved  text (will be added in last)`

`canvas.getObjects().splice(key,0,canvas.getObjects().pop()); //@ reposition it to the old curved object position`

and the rendered it and it works.

I believe there might be some other  better way rather than re-creating element and then doing all the steps for fixing.